# UIView::addSubView obstructs the navigation bar originally at the top

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimageview

I designed a very simple interface for an ipad device: UIView + a navigation bar.

Then after the view is load, it will download an image from a location and use the following method to display it:

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    UIImage* testImg = [UIImage imageWithData:_networkData];
    UIImageView* testView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:testImg];
    [_view addSubview:testView];
    [testView release];
}
```

The problem is now the new UIImage occupies the whole visible area of the Ipad.

I wonder how can I fix this issue? I suppose I have to find out the frame of the display area in the original view, and then assign it to the UIImageView instance?

Answer (score 1):

`initWithImage` will automatically adjust the frame to match the size of the image you're passing in. To tell the `UIImageView` to take the same size as its parent view you could just add the following line before you add the subview:

```
testView.frame = _view.bounds
```

...we use `bounds` rather than `frame` because the superview may have an offset that we don't want the image view to have.

Comment: Did not work, but investigation continues. Thanks for answering!

Comment: Weird - let me know if there's anything else you come up with.